# Why does my Sharepoint workflow not trigger for other users when they submit a form? (SP 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, permissions

I created a custom form and on my permissions when I click submit, it adds to the list and then the workflow fires and I'm emailed the details. When a user in my custom permissions group does it, it adds to the list but does not trigger the workflow.
Permissions they have:

Add Item
View Item
View Pages
Use Remote Interfaces
Open

Comment: I understand you are running an SP 2013 farm, but which workflow platform are you using? 2010 or 2013? The 2013 platform means you have a Workflow Manager farm up and running.

Comment: 2013 as well, I don't actually have access to the workflow farm.

Comment: Is the workflow writing anything to the associated workflow history list, i.e., does it have any log actions? Do your users have permissions to write to that list?

Answer (score 0):

Give your users "Edit Items" permission as well. Since you mentioned that you do not want the users to edit the form you can either

1. Create another second list. Give users permission to edit the list 1 but not list 2. Use your workflow on list 1 to fire the email and also copy data from list 1 to list 2. You can secure the second list by not giving your users any access to it and use an [app step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx) to copy items from list 1 to list 2.
2. Add custom logic to the form to prevent user from editing the field (for example you can create two views: one to be shown the first time and the other non-editable view for other times) I don't recommend this, as this is a client-side solution and isn't truly preventing the user from editing the form data.

If you really do not want to change the permissions and create a second list, then instead of a list workflow, create a site workflow with 2 stages and you manually start it once. Add a workflow action to make the workflow wait till an item is added to your current list (this is stage 1). Then in stage 2, set it up to send the email. Then route the workflow back to stage 1. The process will just repeat.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "This does not provide an answer". Problem is that workflow is not firing and that is because to initiate a workflow the user must at least have "Edit Items" permission level. So, the OP needs to elevate the permissions of his user group.

Comment: The problem with this is, I give them the ability to edit my form. I do not want them to be able to do that, ps sorry for delay

Comment: Well, if that's the case you have to use a work around for that. I will suggest a few but please note that the solution to your original problem is a permission issue. So, in order to start the workflow you have no choice but to elevate permissions. I will edit my original answer to suggest some workarounds.